# Firebase - iOS App Installation on iPhone X is not working

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, ipa, firebase-app-distribution

I uploaded an iOS enterprise build using App-Distribution feature of Firebase Console and shared with my testers.
We are able to download it on all devices except on iPhone X. The error shows "os version not supported". On click of this error, it displays details that "The developer needs to upload a build that supports iOS 10.15". Please check screenshots for reference.

Please note that iPhone X have iOS 13.3. I suspect not be an iOS version issue, because I downloaded app on my personal iPhone XR which has iOS 13.3.

[image: First error]

[image: Second Error]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. This is reproduced only in iPhone 6 plus for me.

Comment: Hey guys just disable desktop site and enable mobile site. You will see download option. It worked for me...

Answer (score 9):

Safari Browser Desktop mode was the culprit. If turned on, any distribution provider's script will think the link was opened it mac instead of iOS.

No need to reset the phone in my case!!!

Answer (score 8):

## Edit:

Actually [Ram's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63780940/9901765) works

- Go into settings
- Safari
- Request Desktop Website
- Turn off the switch

## Old:

For me erasing all content and settings worked.

#### Steps:

- open Settings
- go to General
- Reset (at the bottom)
- Erase All Content and Settings

### Remember to do some backup of your data because it will erase all the content.

I didn't check if Reset All Settings option works.

I hope it will help you!

Comment: FYI - I'm having the exact same problem (I'm on 13.3, and firebase says I need a build that supports 10.15). For curiosity, I tried Reset All Settings option - it did not work. I hesitate to also erase all content, so I'm going to try updating to 13.6 next.

Comment: New info - the update didn't work either. (After I updated to 13.6, the new error said I needed a build that suppots 10.15.4.) In the end your solution, Erase All Content and Settings, did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Bartlomiej. I will try this. I have to take permission from my senior as device belongs to the company I am working for. :)